# ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Tags: python, datetime

I have a text file with two columns of time values like this:

21:28:07.638502 21:28:07.636

Yes, one column has extra digits for the time.  I'm trying to just read all lines, get the time difference in microseconds ... etc.

If I try something like the following, I would get error.

```
import datetime
format="%H:%M:%S.%f"
with open(file) as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines():
        line.strip()
        [a,b]=line.split(' ')
        dta=datetime.datetime.strptime(a,format)
        dtb=datetime.datetime.strptime(b,format)
        diff=dta-dtb
        print(diff.microseconds)
```

I'm not sure what the "Unconverted data" comes from.  There's nothing after the "remains:" in the error message. What exactly is data remains?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
  tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 340, in _strptime
  data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Comment: You actually don't need strip at all if you just use, `a,b =line.split()`. Also file objects are iterable so there is no need for readlines, just iterate over the file object.

Comment: You could improve the readability of your code with `a, b = line.split()`. No need to write `[a, b]` as in this context `a, b` constructs a tuple, the members of which are the ones returned by `line.split`. `str.split` uses a whitespace as a separator by default, so no need to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strip` does not work in place, you have to assign it to actually remove the new line character:

```
line = line.strip()
```

Comment: I'm a mor on.  Thanks

Comment: `line.strip(" ")` would also be very different to `line.strip()`

Comment: @BillyK, you're _not_. Asking questions doesn't mean being stupid as this is a means of learning.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Brainfart on that. Sheesh, you saved me a lot of trouble. I read `split <-> strip` :(